# In the song "muss i denn" , how should I understand "No sei mein' Lieb' vorbei"?

Tags: translation, dialect, lyrics, swabian

In the famous song "muss i denn", I see these two lines(I know it's old German).
(ref : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muss_i_denn)

```
Denk du net, wenn i 'ne Andre seh',
No sei mein' Lieb' vorbei;
```

Is it

```
Denk du nicht, wenn ich eine Andre sehe,
noch sei mein Liebe vorbei
```

?
is 'sei' the imperative form of sein? (I guess so). and `vorbei sein` is something like `be finished`. I can't exactly understand the 'No' part here. How is `No` here literally translated? Is it `noch` or `nicht`?
I think this song is about the true love and commitment of a man to a woman and is very beautiful and touching.

Comment: Second line should be translated as: Dann sei meine Liebe vorbei. "No" is dialect and not an abbreviation of "noch".

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks.  Still I don't know how to exactly embrace it.

Comment: ... and 'sei' is Konjunktiv I Präsenz. Even under the option of seeing another one they won't be gone. At least so they say :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well known traditional swabian (schwäbischer) song that was also made world-famous by Elvis Presley at some point.

The [swabian](http://schwaebisches-woerterbuch.de/default.asp) "no" (or "nåh" with a closed "a") means "dann" *(then)*, and "sei" is a Konjunktiv of indirect speech. So a translation to high German would be:

> Denk du nicht, wenn ich eine Andre sehe,
> dann sei meine Liebe vorbei.

> Don't think that, if I see someone else *["eine Andre" is female],* then my love will be over.

The song is the farewell to his girl of a young man who has to leave town, maybe for a journeyman's waltz. He promises to be true and faithful and to return in the following autumn, when grapes are harvested, and marry her.

Comment: But Swabian dictionaries say the translation of no is noch.

Comment: @mtwde: what can I say, my father's family live near Aalen, I don't speak it, but "no" for "dann" is pretty basic. Edit : http://schwaebisches-woerterbuch.de/default.asp, search for "dann" and you get "nåh".

Comment: @mtwde: also here: https://www.topster.de/deutsch-schwaebisch/, they write "noh", but the swedish å is actually closer.

Comment: Clearly in some high allemanic dialects "no" _can_ mean noch, though.

Comment: @HalvarF Yeah, but if you search for "noch" in both you get "no" ^^

Comment: Anyhow "Noch" does not make any sense in this context.

Comment: @mtwde: In the Swabian spoken in the region where I grew up, "no" can mean both "dann" and "noch", but there is a difference in pronunciation. As HalvarF already said, the pronunciation of the "no" meaning "dann" sounds like "nåh". On the other hand, the pronunciation of the "no" meaning "noch" sounds like "noh" as in the German word "Floh".

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments. I didn't catch the objective phrase of 'Denk' is the whole following statements including No~. So I'll understand that if 'No' is 'dann' , then it's like 'don't you think when I see another girl, then(=so) my love ends' . And if 'No' is 'noch', then it can be translated 'don't you think even if I see another girl, still never think my love ends'. Thank you all!

Comment: not quite. In this context, "No" will never mean "noch" and it is pronounced "nåh". Don't let yourself confuse by the comments - The answer is perfectly correct. The confusion is just a result of the imperfect (or rather, ambiguous) transliteration of the Swabian dialect.